# Returning text when text contains key element using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a function in python using regex that should return text when an element of that text is matched but the outputs I'm getting aren't as expected and I'm not sure what is going wrong.

My function is as below:

```
def latin_ish_words(text):
    
    latin = re.findall('tion|ex|ph|ost', text, re.I)
    
    return latin
```

When I pass `latin_ish_words("This functions as expected"))` it returns the elements 'tion' and 'ex' rather than 'functions' and 'expected'

If someone could tell me where I've gone wrong, I'd be most appreciative!

Many thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returns matching text - and that's what you saw. If you want to look for specific string within words, your search should state that.
I think `\w*(?:tion|ex|ph|ost)\w*` should help you find what you're expecting (you may need to enable greedy matching).

Let's look at the modifications:

- `\w` - matches a "word-character" (letters in upper- or lowercase, digits or underscore)
- `*` - previous pattern needs to match between zero and unlimited times
- `(?:` - followed by a match of the rx within (..)

So basically we're just allowing word characters before and after. If you wanted to be more strict and only accept letters, use `[A-z]*` instead of `\w*`.

Comment: Thank you so much MBaas - could you explain what these additional elements are performing? Really sorry but I'm very beginner with regex!

Comment: I modified my answer to include those details ;)